# PHP number_format() and round() not producing valid upper-range results

Tags: php, rounding

A log I've built isn't getting correct numbers reported...

> 0.01% - 1,362 (incorrect %)
>
> 9.13% - 814 (correct)
>
> 0.66% - 59 (correct)

Here is my code...

```
$count2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);
$n = 100/$count2*number_format($value);
echo round($n,2).'%';
```

Comment: You're using number_format prematurely. number_format returns a string.. which you're then rounding. In general, don't do any formatting or rounding until the very end.

Answer (score 7):

`number_format` is going to add commas and such and that will mess up `round` as it doesn't expect strings.  Try using `number_format` after using round like this:

```
$count2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);
$n = 100/$count2*$value;
echo number_format(round($n,2)).'%';
```

Comment: The round doesn't work, it only gives me whole numbers (1,2,3,9,22,34, etc) not 12.02, 5.23. It did fix the other problem though.

Comment: @John try casting $count and $value as floats?  e.g. 100.00/(float)$count2*(float)$value

Comment: I removed `number_format()` and it works fine now. I'm not sure why I used it, none of the numbers could ever be higher than 100% for that log!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Your question's problem was multiplying by a string.

Answer (score 1):

'Number Format' is adding a comma in values over a thousand therefor multiplying by a string.

Answer (score -1):

Removing `number_format()` from both lines corrected the problem.